# Recommended websocket subprotocols for Angular front end, Spring Java backend?

Tags: angular, websocket, swagger, stomp, spring-websocket

I'm curious if folks have recommendations for the websocket subprotocol to use between an Angular front end client and Java Spring backend server.  Spring has inherent support for STOMP.  It seems like Swagger Socket is another option.  Perhaps Swagger Socket provides better options for swagger documentation.

Does anyone know the pros/cons between different websocket protocols?
Is there a defacto standard subprotocol now?

Thanks